# Are edge cuts, vertex cuts, and cut sets all variously called "cuts"?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, definition, network-flow, discrete-optimization

I've seen "cut" being used to refer to all three, in different places, and sometimes in the same book.

Which does "cut" most commonly refer to?

p.s. I am aware that "cut" itself can be defined to refer to a certain partitioning, but here I am only interested in a cut as a set.